# Could not create task ':app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug'

Tags: android, crashlytics

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not create task ':app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug'.
   > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultValueSourceProviderFactory$ValueSourceProvider.forUseAtConfigurationTime() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

project's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.0'
    }
}
```

app's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

//...
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Downgrading to com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0 helped me, apparently something wrong with the latest version

Comment: I am trying to also use it for Flutter, and I spent several hours figuring this out.. big thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in the Crashlytics plugin that causes an error when used with Gradle 6.1 - Gradle 6.4.1. We'll try to get it fixed in an upcoming release. In the meantime, upgrading to Gradle 6.5+ should fix the error.

Comment: I'm indeed using 6.1.1

Answer (score 5):

Downgrading to com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1 helped me.
Something is wrong with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I use the next versions in the `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:17.0.1"
```

And go to change:

```
File > Project structure > grade version: 6.7.1
```

and work fine the compilation project